# Why I can't use generator function multiple time?

Tags: python, generator

I'm using the following function to apply a sliding window over multiple frames of video:

```
def window(seq, size=3, step=1):
    if size < 1 or step < 1:
        raise ValueError("Error: infinite loops.")
    it = iter(seq)
    result = list(islice(it, size))
    while len(result) == size:
        yield result
        if step >= size:
            result = list(islice(it, step-size, step))
        else:
            result = result[step:] + list(islice(it, step))
```

When I call this function 1 time I got no error but when I call multiple time like this:

```
def window(seq, size=3, step=1):
    if size < 1 or step < 1:
        raise ValueError("Error: infinite loops.")
    it = iter(seq)
    result = list(islice(it, size))
    while len(result) == size:
        yield result
        if step >= size:
            result = list(islice(it, step-size, step))
        else:
            result = result[step:] + list(islice(it, step))



with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    adl_window_list= []
    for items in window(adl_list,55, 5):
        if items[0][48]== items[-1][48] and items[0][49]== items[-1][49]: # Faire correspondre le même numèro de video pour le 1er et derniere élèmen de la liste
            adl_window_list.append(items)

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    falls_window_list= []
    for item in window(falls_list,55, 1):
        stand_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("/-1")]
        fall_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("/1")]
        if stand_indexes and fall_indexes and max(stand_indexes) < min(fall_indexes):
            falls_window_list.append(item)
```

I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-081aa7b2897c> in <module>
    225 with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    226     falls_window_list= []
--> 227     for item in window(falls_list,55, 1):
    228         stand_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("/-1")]
    229         fall_indexes = [idx for idx, elem in enumerate(item) if elem.endswith("/1")]

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I need to create another window function everytime I want to call the function.
I though the generator was created everytime I call the function.

Can you explain me why it doesn't work like this and how can I use the function multiple time without copying it as many time as I want to use it?

Comment: The code you posted won't raise that error. You probably didn't post the actual code that is causing the issue. My guess is in your actual code `window1_list` is called `list`. Also please always post the **whole error message** with **full traceback** when asking a question.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks for your advice, I edited my post

Comment: A generator "consumes" itself as you pull items from it.  When you pull the last item, the generator is exhausted.  If you need to run it again, convert the generator to a list.  You can pull from a list many times.

Comment: That error message says there's a *lot* of code in what you actually ran that didn't make its way into the question. Somewhere in all that code you didn't post, you redefined `window`.

Comment: Between each time I call the `window` function I'm using pandas to create `falls` or `adl` list

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a line that starts with `window = ...` in your code?

Comment: Did you use the Find feature to search for it? Obviously Python interpreter thinks that `window` is an object of type `list`, not a `function`. It's rarely wrong about such things.

Comment: @Selcuk So sorry, I realise that I used a loop like  this `for window in falls_window_list: `, that's probably where is my mistake